undefined reference to library functions that I have properly linked?
whilst trying to have a slightly modified version of one of the examples for using the Discord Game SDK to generate a Rich Presence for a user, I have encountered errors when trying to link said libraries to my code.
The libraries, headers, etc, can be found here: https://discord.com/developers/docs/developer-tools/game-sdk
(I am using v3.2.1)
My code is as such:
#include <iostream>
#include <csignal>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>

#include "../include/discord/discord.h"

struct DiscordState {
    std::unique_ptr<discord::Core> core;
};

namespace {
    volatile bool interrupted{ false };
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    // Make sure we have the right number of arguments
    if (argc < 2 || argc > 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Incorrect number of arguments: expected 1, received %d.\n", (argc - 1));
        fprintf(stderr, "USAGE: ./StremioRichPresence [CLIENT_ID]\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("StremioRichPresence\n");

    // Check if the argument represents an actual integer for a client id, otherwise complain.
    signed long int clientID = NULL;
    try {
        clientID = std::stoi(argv[1]);
    } catch (const std::invalid_argument& e) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Argument for client ID is not a valid number.\n");
        exit(1);
    } catch (const std::out_of_range& e) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Argument for client ID is a number too large to fit into the specified integer type.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("clientID is %ld", clientID);


    DiscordState state;
    discord::Core* core{};
    auto response = discord::Core::Create(clientID, DiscordCreateFlags_Default, &core);
    state.core.reset(core);

    if (!state.core) {
        std::cout << "Failed to instantiate Discord!";
        std::exit(-1);
    }

    discord::Activity activity{};
    activity.SetDetails("Fruit Tarts");
    activity.SetState("Pop Snacks");
    activity.GetAssets().SetSmallImage("the");
    activity.GetAssets().SetSmallText("i mage");
    activity.GetAssets().SetLargeImage("the");
    activity.GetAssets().SetLargeText("u mage");
    activity.SetType(discord::ActivityType::Playing);
    state.core->ActivityManager().UpdateActivity(activity, [](discord::Result result) {
        std::cout << ((result == discord::Result::Ok) ? "Succeeded" : "Failed")
            << " updating activity!\n";
    });


    std::signal(SIGINT, [](int) {
        interrupted = true;
    });
    do {
        state.core->RunCallbacks();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(16));
    } while (!interrupted);

    return 0;
}


I use the following command to compile:
g++ -L/home/judith/Code/StremioRichPresence/lib/x86_64/ -l:discord_game_sdk.so -I/home/judith/Code/StremioRichPresence/include/discord src/main.cpp -o main.o
And in return I am greeted by these errors:
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccMXqSZb.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1fe): undefined reference to `discord::Core::Create(long, unsigned long, discord::Core**)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x286): undefined reference to `discord::Activity::SetDetails(char const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x29f): undefined reference to `discord::Activity::SetState(char const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x2ae): undefined reference to `discord::Activity::GetAssets()'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x2c3): undefined reference to `discord::ActivityAssets::SetSmallImage(char const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x2d2): undefined reference to `discord::Activity::GetAssets()'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x2e7): undefined reference to `discord::ActivityAssets::SetSmallText(char const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x2f6): undefined reference to `discord::Activity::GetAssets()'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x30b): undefined reference to `discord::ActivityAssets::SetLargeImage(char const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x31a): undefined reference to `discord::Activity::GetAssets()'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x32f): undefined reference to `discord::ActivityAssets::SetLargeText(char const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x343): undefined reference to `discord::Activity::SetType(discord::ActivityType)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x35a): undefined reference to `discord::Core::ActivityManager()'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x38f): undefined reference to `discord::ActivityManager::UpdateActivity(discord::Activity const&, std::function<void (discord::Result)>)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x3d1): undefined reference to `discord::Core::RunCallbacks()'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccMXqSZb.o: in function `std::default_delete<discord::Core>::operator()(discord::Core*) const':
main.cpp:(.text._ZNKSt14default_deleteIN7discord4CoreEEclEPS1_[_ZNKSt14default_deleteIN7discord4CoreEEclEPS1_]+0x1e): undefined reference to `discord::Core::~Core()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status


my codebase is laid out like this:
.
├── build
├── include
│   └── discord
│       ├── achievement_manager.cpp
│       ├── achievement_manager.h
│       ├── activity_manager.cpp
│       ├── activity_manager.h
│       ├── application_manager.cpp
│       ├── application_manager.h
│       ├── core.cpp
│       ├── core.h
│       ├── discord.h
│       ├── event.h
│       ├── ffi.h
│       ├── image_manager.cpp
│       ├── image_manager.h
│       ├── lobby_manager.cpp
│       ├── lobby_manager.h
│       ├── network_manager.cpp
│       ├── network_manager.h
│       ├── overlay_manager.cpp
│       ├── overlay_manager.h
│       ├── relationship_manager.cpp
│       ├── relationship_manager.h
│       ├── storage_manager.cpp
│       ├── storage_manager.h
│       ├── store_manager.cpp
│       ├── store_manager.h
│       ├── types.cpp
│       ├── types.h
│       ├── user_manager.cpp
│       ├── user_manager.h
│       ├── voice_manager.cpp
│       └── voice_manager.h
├── lib
│   ├── aarch64
│   │   ├── discord_game_sdk.bundle
│   │   └── discord_game_sdk.dylib
│   └── x86_64
│       ├── discord_game_sdk.bundle
│       ├── discord_game_sdk.dll
│       ├── discord_game_sdk.dll.lib
│       ├── discord_game_sdk.dylib
│       └── discord_game_sdk.so
├── README.md
└── src
    └── main.cpp


src/main.cpp should be first. -l... should be last.

Or cmake and skip all of this.

@3CxEZiVlQ i did
"g++ src/main.cpp -o main.o -L/home/judith/Code/StremioRichPresence/lib/x86_64 -l:discord_game_sdk.so -I/home/judith/StremioRichPresence/include/discord" and it gave me the same errors

@sweenish when i tried this with cmake it couldn't find the libraries

Then, you likely link with an incompatible library.

Probably unrelated, but volatile is not a way to synchronise threads. std::atomic<bool> might be.

Given the relative path include and the project layout, my conclusion is that the library was never actually built and installed. A lack of edit to show the cmake list file is also problematic. Using libraries in C++ doesn’t have to suck. For me, vcpkg + cmake does the trick really well. I have come to hate Conan, but my work is still on 1.x. Maybe 2.x is nicer. But I don’t like the whole meta-build-system-with-package-management-as-a-side-effect nature of Conan.

@Judith. You are right, your linkage errors are not caused by linking discord_game_sdk.so before the object file(s)
that refer to it, but that mistake would cause such linkage errors, so you will have to correct that mistake
in your question to get the question reopened. Making the correction in a comment is not enough.
